# Setting up full page ads

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7, admob, ads

I am using Admob Mediation service with an `Interstitial` ad type for a full page ad.

Documentation here: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced#ios

I am trying to replicate the full page ad setup in Words with Friends and other game apps. Where the full screen ad is shown then a delayed close button is shown. Can this be completed with the above setup?

In an ideal world I would like to delay the close button being shown and also randomly place the close button in one of the four corners.

Comment: Adding a bounty to bring attention to question. Ideally I would like to use Admob as they are the leading provider for ios mobile ads. I need to know specifically if I can delay the close button showing/show in a different place.

Comment: All you will achieve by delaying the close button is that you will annoy the user. I know that personally I would delete the app immediately as a SCAM if they show ads and wont let me close them out right away. I did it with the "with Friends" series. Also by moving the close button around you are only annoying them further. The user should know how to close the ad. Though I cant comment on what Apple will do, I would deny that app if I were them simply because its a bad user experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes,** the setup displayed in the `GADInterstitial` documentation should create and display an interstitial ad such as you describe. You shouldn't have to do anything special to make the close box show up after a delay -- that's something that the ad will implement if it's what the advertiser wants. Just follow the directions in the docs -- wait for the ad to finish loading, and then call:

```
[interstitial_ presentFromRootViewController:self];
```

(Substitute your own variable name if you use something other than `interstitial_`, of course).

> In an ideal world I would like to delay the close button being shown and also randomly place the close button in one of the four corners.

You shouldn't try to control the placement or display of ad controls like the close button. Again, the ad itself will manage that. I'm sure your goal is to increase your app's click-through rate, or more generally to maximize your advertising income. But there's a reason beyond ease of use that ad networks make their SDK's very simple to integrate: they don't want you to mess with the way ads are displayed. At all. Not even a little bit.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The ad is presented when the above method is run. When the ad is presented so is the close button, is there a way to only display the ad and then later display the close button. You say its something if its what the advertiser wants, but not sure where/how to configure as you mention? thanks

Comment: The appearance of the close button isn't something that you control. Some ads will have a close box there immediately, while others will show it after a delay. **Just let the ad do its thing.** Also, remember that during development you're probably looking at some basic test ads. Since it's a pain to have to wait 5 seconds to dismiss a test ad such ads are less likely to include the delay. Once your app is showing real ads, you'll be more likely to see ads that call for a delay.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a timer that creates and adds a button to your view after x-time

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. The ad itself should take care of displaying the close box at the appropriate time.

Comment: @Caleb is correct, the close button is automatically shown by the ad at present

Comment: is it possible to remove or hide close button of ad? @Sean